# FFTW linking issue in R 3.2.2 running on Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite

Tags: r, osx-yosemite, fftw

I am trying to resolve what seems to be a dependency on fftw for a package that should run in R 3.2.2. The package's authors claims this dependency does not exist anymore, but when I try to install the package I receive the following output

```
> install.packages("seewave")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
 compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘seewave’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘seewave’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/seewave_2.0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2485930 bytes (2.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.4 MB

* installing *source* package ‘seewave’ ...
** package ‘seewave’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG
-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include
-fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c stft.c -o stft.o 
stft.c:44:6: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable] 
       int i = 0; 
           ^ 
1 warning generated.
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress 
-L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib  
-o seewave.so stft.o -lfftw3 -lsndfile  
-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: library not found for -lfftw3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [seewave.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘seewave’
* removing        /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/seewave’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘seewave’ had non-zero exit status
```

A package named fftw is already in R, in the version 1.0.3. However, when I go into the terminal and type the command below, I receive an output pointing to the lack of 'linking' of fftw

```
$ brew install fftw
Warning: fftw-3.3.4_1 already installed, it's just not linked
```

Interestingly (or foolishly), there is a fftw3 folder in a surely incorrect path, but there is not a path for fftw3.3.4_1

```
/Users/mario/fftw-3.3.3
```

How could I make the correct linking and perhaps solve the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @WhiteViking NO, `sudo` is never necessary with `brew link`!

Comment: @IKavanagh You provide a nice and detailed answer. I deleted my wrong comment about `sudo brew link`. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you may have previously attempted to install FFTW from source, owing to the presence of `/Users/mario/fftw-3.3.3` and the fact the Homebrew version is not linked. If you have previously installed FFTW from source `brew doctor` should output something similar to

```
Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/fftw3.h
```

**Note:** *There should be more warnings for a correct installation.*

When you download and extract FFTW the resulting folder will have the name `fftw-<major>.<minor>.<patch>`. This is most likely what `/Users/mario/fftw-3.3.3` is. You should be able to uninstall this version of FFTW with

```
$ cd /Users/mario/fftw-3.3.3
$ make uninstall
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf fftw-3.3.3/
```

**Note:** `sudo` may be needed depending on how you installed it. If no `makefile` exists you will need to create it with

```
$ ./configure
$ make uninstall
```

Now `brew doctor` should not output anything about FFTW and you can safely execute

```
$ brew link fftw
```

to link FFTW. If, on the off-chance, this still does not work you can use

```
$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run fftw
```

This will, because of `--dry-run`, tell you what files Homebrew will need to overwrite to correctly link FFTW.

```
$ brew link --overwrite fftw
```

should then be safe to run as Homebrew is designed not to mess up your system. Now the issues with linking FFTW when installing the R package should be resolved and your installation should proceed as expected.

---

#### Aside

Using `sudo` with `brew link` is **never** the right option. The correct method for linking Homebrew formulas is as described above.

1. Correct any warnings from `brew doctor`
2. Check what `brew link --overwrite --dry-run` will overwrite
3. Link formula with `brew link` or `brew link --overwrite`